# Kuberenetes deployment Failing

Tags: docker, kubernetes

My Kubernetes deployment is failing. Can anybody advise what could be going wrong.

My observation: When I remove the volume mount things the service bounce back

```
   volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /app
      volumes:
       - name: my-volume
         hostPath:
          path: /tmp/vpath
```

Remove the above piece of the code

```
  State:          Waiting
  Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
  Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       ContainerCannotRun
  Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./main": stat ./main: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Here is my deployment file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: stservice
  name: stservice
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: stservice
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
        kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: stservice
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: stservice
          name: stservice
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5001
            - containerPort: 5002
          volumeMounts:
            - name: my-volume
              mountPath: /app
      volumes:
       - name: my-volume
         hostPath:
          path: /tmp/vpath 
status: {}


apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.22.0 (955b78124)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: stservice
  name: stservice
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "5001"
      port: 5001
      targetPort: 5001
    - name: "5002"
      port: 5002
      targetPort: 5002
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: stservice
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Can anyone advice why having volume mount causes this failure

```
Message:      OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "./main": stat ./main: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be mounting the volume over the Dockerfile **WORKDIR**, so you are overwriting the file that it is looking for and throwing this error: "... /main: no such file or directory:".

If that is the issue update the docker WORKDIR or the mount path. If that is not the issue please include the Dockerfile.

Comment: Mauro : WORKDIR /app -- yes app is mounted over my workdir. Let me try your suggestion